# Adding custom Command which returns string, typescript

Tags: typescript, ui-automation, cypress

I am new to cypress and I am trying to learn cypress with typescript.

I am facing an issue when I am trying to add a custom command.

```
Cypress.Commands.add('getEnvURL', (environment) => {

    if(environment === ('Dev')){

        return 'testURL';
    } else if (environment === ('Stagging')){        
        return 'StaggingURL';
    }
});


declare global {
    namespace Cypress {
      // tslint:disable-next-line:interface-name
      interface Chainable<Subject> {
        getEnvURL(environment: string): string;        
      }
    }
  }
```

**SPEC FILE**

```
it('Login Test', () => {
cy.visit(cy.getEnvURL(Cypress.env('environment')));
 });
```

when I am trying to call the getEnvURL() custom method from spec file, I am expecting that it will return the URL string. when I am running the test it's not doing anything.

Can someone help me to solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue should be with the line of your code.

```
cy.visit(cy.getEnvURL(Cypress.env('environment')))
```

cy.getEnvURL returns an object rather than the return values 'testURL' or 'StaggingURL'.

can you try this code instead?

```
cy.getEnvURL(Cypress.env('username')).then(($url) => {
        cy.visit($url)
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Speaking of cy commands or custom ones, they always return results asynchronously. You only consume actual result data in the **then** block.
https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/introduction-to-cypress.html#Subject-Management

---

In my opinion, cy command is not what you need. I expect the variable **environment** is set before your app starts and will not be changed at runtime. If so, you only need to create a simple module, **test-utils.ts** or anything, placed under **cypress/utils**.

```
export const getEnvUrl = (env: string) => {
  const env = Cypress.env('environment')
  if (env === 'staging') {
    return 'staging-url'
  } else {
    return 'test-url'
  }
}
```

In a cypress test, you can use it straighforward

```
cy.visit(getEnvUrl())
```